# Trigger change for custom attr select 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select option that uses select 2 plugin like this

```
<select id ="temp">
    <option value="1" data-width="24" data-length="12">First</option>
    <option value="3" data-width="32" data-length="24" >Second</option>
    <option value="1" data-width="16" data-length="16" >Third</option>
    <option value="1" data-width="8" data-length="4" >Fourth</option>
</select>
```

I want to get data width and length from user inputs from keyboard. I call them is **customWidth** and **customLength**.

Expert results:

> When user type true `customWidth` and `customLength` select2 trigger
>   change selected value. Example: `customWidth` = 8 and `customLength` =
>   4, select 2 should be trigger selected this option 
>   `<option value="1" data-width="8" data-length="4" >Fourth</option>`

Thank you for help.

Comment: Please create a working code snippet that replicates your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by finding an option that has same width and  length  by [data attribute](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) the, if found select it then trigger change so the slect2 take new val .

See below working snippet :

```js
$(function() {

  $customWidth = $("#customwidth");
  $customLength = $("#customlength");

  $customWidth.on("input", function(e) {
    if( $customLength.val() && this.value ) {
    var el = $("#temp").find('option[data-width=' + this.value + '][data-length=' +  $customLength.val() + ']');
      if (el.length > 0)
        el.attr('selected', 'selected').trigger("change");
    }
  });

  $customLength.on("input", function(e) {
    if( $customWidth.val() && this.value ) {
    var el = $("#temp").find('option[data-width=' + $customWidth.val() + '][data-length=' + this.value + ']');
    if (el.length > 0)
      el.attr('selected', 'selected').trigger("change");
    }
  });

  $('#temp').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select'
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>

customWidth : <input id="customwidth" /><br/><br/> customLength : <input id="customlength" /><br/><br/>

<select id="temp" style="width: 300px">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1" data-width="24" data-length="12">First</option>
  <option value="3" data-width="32" data-length="24">Second</option>
  <option value="1" data-width="16" data-length="16">Third</option>
  <option value="1" data-width="8" data-length="4">Fourth</option>
</select>
```

Comment: My pleasure :) @chinhnguyen

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly working only for width. Try yourself to implement length too.

**HTML**

```
<select id ="temp">
<option value="1" data-width="24" data-length="12">First</option>
<option value="3" data-width="32" data-length="24" >Second</option>
<option value="1" data-width="16" data-length="16" >Third</option>
<option value="1" data-width="8" data-length="4" >Fourth</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="width">
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#temp').select2({

});

$('#width').keyup(function(){
var widthVal= $(this).val()

  $("#temp option").each(function(){        
    if($(this).attr('data-width')==widthVal){   
      $('#temp option[data-width="'+widthVal+'"]').prop('selected','selected').change()     
    }  
  })  
})
```

Comment: Thanks for answer me. have a nice day